# Do the emulated samples from the 'gold' book or from ImgTec work on any of your 64-bit Win 7 machines?

Tags: opengl-es

Either the OpenGL_ES_Programming_Guide_v1.0.2 samples or the Imagination Technologies\POWERVR SDK\OGLES2_WINDOWS_PCEMULATION_2.06.26.0649\Binaries\Demos?

Either or both above using either AMD's OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator or Imagination Technologies' PVRVFrame emulator?

Does anybody see runtime activity other than blank client areas with nothing in them for either of those two example sets under 64 bit Windows 7?

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the AMD demos, but the Imagination ones get tested on a 64bit Windows 7 system internally so it seems more likely that it's a problem with your graphics setup. What card do you have and are the drivers for it up to date?

It might also be worth getting in contact directly here:

http://www.imgtec.com/forum/default.asp

or by email: devtech@imgtec.com

BTW A new version of this SDK has just been published, it might be worth trying that as well.